# How to limit google autocomplete results to City and Country only

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, google-maps-api-3

I am using google autocomplete places javascript to return suggested results for my searchbox , what I need is to only show the city and the country related to the characters entered but google api will give a lot of general places results which I dont need , so how to limit the result to show only city and the country .

I am using the following Example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
   body {
         font-family: sans-serif;
         font-size: 14px;
   }
</style>

<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Places Autocomplete</title>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function initialize() {
      var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
   }
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

</head>
<body>
   <div>
      <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="on">
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 441, accepted):

You can try the country restriction

```
function initialize() {

 var options = {
  types: ['(cities)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
 };

 var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
 var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}
```

### More info:

**[ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2)** can be used to restrict results to specific groups. Currently, you can use componentRestrictions to filter by country.
The country must be passed as as a two character, ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 compatible country code.

---

[Officially assigned country codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2)

Comment: Do you know if there are any usage limit on auto complete queries if I am not loading any maps? I know there is a 25,000 usage limit if I load maps

Comment: This awsome examples. How to prepare all results to format like this: city, region, country?

Comment: is there a way where i don't have to limit the country?

Comment: try removing the restriction from the options.

Comment: It's August 2014. Is it already possible to show only countries and cities? For e.g. when I type Mil, the result is Milan, Bergamo, Italy. I need only Milan, Italy. Adding all countries one by one is not an option.

Comment: Hi @erdomester hope this post gives some insight. https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4233

Comment: Is it possible to specify more than one country?

Comment: Thanks for the `types: ['(cities)']` Was looking for this!

Comment: @bart apparently it is not possible. Please star [this issue](https://goo.gl/iijOcl) if you want that feature.

Comment: @bart : Having the same problem for multiple countries, stared the issue that google doesn't seem to take much care of.

Comment: works great, but is there any way (don't want to go too much off topic) to make the search less strict ? I mostly work with french cities and if accents or hyphens do not match exactly the name of the city you are looking for it won't get any result

Comment: @Francois, using google map API can we add multiple cities in single textbox? Example I want to add multiple locations for "Preferred Location" for Job etc.

Comment: if we use types: ['(cities)'] then it will not allowed us to search by zip code here.

Comment: adding type cities doen't allow to search location by zipcode.

Comment: apparently it allows restricting by more than one country by now: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-multiple-countries

Comment: Also, using types: ['(regions)'] instead of '(cities)' allows searching for postal code as well

Comment: I want to allow to choose city, bar, restaurant, hotels, airports and other small locations but NOT STATE NAME and COUNTRY NAME in google autocomplete, how can i do, please share any suggestion, thanks a lot :)

Comment: "Currently, you can use componentRestrictions to filter by up to 5 countries" https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

Comment: Does it matter if the function is called ```initialize```? When does this get called in the page?

Comment: Guys...is it possible to restrict the length of the formatted address? I want it not greater than 50 characters.

Answer (score 29):

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
   body {
         font-family: sans-serif;
         font-size: 14px;
   }
</style>

<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Places Autocomplete</title>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function initialize() {
      var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
      var options = {
        types: ['geocode'] //this should work !
      };
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
   }
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

</head>
<body>
   <div>
      <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="on">
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
var options = {
  types: ['geocode'] //this should work !
};
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

reference to other types: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/supported_types.html#table2

Comment: check this code right from google. they made a filtering example
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html#adding_autocomplete

Comment: autocomplete object will not accept two variables, only one variable can be accepted which is 'geocode'.  I don't know how to solve this problem . Google documentation list a lot of type but none can be accepted.

Comment: would the same parameters work for `AutocompleteService`?

Answer (score 26):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10170421/2200476) given by Francois results in listing all the cities from a country. But if the requirement is to list all the regions (cities + states + other regions etc) in a country or the establishments in the country, you can filter results accordingly by changing types.

**List only cities in the country**

```
 var options = {
  types: ['(cities)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
 };
```

**List all cities, states and regions in the country**

```
 var options = {
  types: ['(regions)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
 };
```

**List all establishments — such as restaurants, stores, and offices in the country**

```
  var options = {
      types: ['establishment'],
      componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
     };
```

Also, you can add multiple types to the result filter like this:

**List all the establishments equal to schools and drugstores, and places of type neighborhoods, locality, and sublocality**

```
  var options = {
      types: ['school','drugstore','neighborhood', 'locality', 'sublocality'],
      componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
     };
```

**Note:** See the [available types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/supported_types) and note that you can combine only the items at table 1 and table 2, and up to 5 items. Table 3 don't allow to combine.

More information and options available at

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

Hope this might be useful to someone

Answer (score 15):

try this

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
   body {
         font-family: sans-serif;
         font-size: 14px;
   }
</style>

<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Places Autocomplete</title>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places&region=in" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function initialize() {
      var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
   }
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

</head>
<body>
   <div>
      <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="on">
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"

Change this to: "region=in" (in=india)

"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&region=in" type="text/javascript"

Comment: We need list of cities, list of states, list of areas and so on

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The simplest and fastest way to achieve the result that the OP's asking. and it worked for me.

Answer (score 14):

Basically same as the accepted answer, but updated with new type and multiple country restrictions:

```
function initialize() {

 var options = {
  types: ['(regions)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: ["us", "de"]}
 };

 var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
 var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}
```

Using `'(regions)'` instead of `'(cities)'` allows to search by postal code as well as city name.

See official documentation, Table 3:
https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types

Comment: Took me 5 minutes to figure out it's `'(regions)'` type, not `'regions'` ...

Answer (score 9):

I've been playing around with the Google Autocomplete API for a bit and here's the best solution I could find for limiting your results to only countries:

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
var result = autocomplete.getPlace();
console.log(result); // take a look at this result object
console.log(result.address_components); // a result has multiple address components

for(var i = 0; i < result.address_components.length; i += 1) {
  var addressObj = result.address_components[i];
  for(var j = 0; j < addressObj.types.length; j += 1) {
    if (addressObj.types[j] === 'country') {
      console.log(addressObj.types[j]); // confirm that this is 'country'
      console.log(addressObj.long_name); // confirm that this is the country name
    }
  }
}
```

If you look at the result object that's returned, you'll see that there's an address_components array which will contain several objects representing different parts of an address. Within each of these objects, it will contain a 'types' array and within this 'types' array, you'll see the different labels associated with an address, including one for country.

Comment: Is there a way to restrict to only certain states in the US, or even exclude particular states?

Comment: @santafebound I'm trying to do the same thing (for a specific state in Australia). From the documentation it looks like the answer is 'No[t yet]', but I'm hoping to find a way to intercept the `response` object and restrict it by other keys in the data.

Answer (score 7):

For country you can use this:

```
components=country:pak

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?&input=${text-to-search}&key=${API_KEY}&language=en&components=country:pak
```

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution for myself

```
var acService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
var autocompleteItems = [];

acService.getPlacePredictions({
    types: ['(regions)']
}, function(predictions) {
    predictions.forEach(function(prediction) {
        if (prediction.types.some(function(x) {
                return x === "country" || x === "administrative_area1" || x === "locality";
            })) {
            if (prediction.terms.length < 3) {
                autocompleteItems.push(prediction);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

this solution only show city and country..

Comment: Can you provide the full code list with autocomplete

Answer (score 4):

Also you will need to zoom and center the map due to your country restrictions!

Just use zoom and center parameters! ;)

```
function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: countries['us'].zoom,
    center: countries['us'].center,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false
  };

  ... all other code ...

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example Using Google Complete API</title>   
  </head>
  <body>

<form>
   <input id="geocomplete" type="text" placeholder="Type an address/location"/>
    </form>
   <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/jquery.geocomplete.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(function(){        
    $("#geocomplete").geocomplete();                           
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

For more information visit [this link](https://vaja906programmingworld.wordpress.com/2016/07/15/google-autocomplete-api-search-location/)

Answer (score 0):

For cities you can try this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=new delhi&types=locality&key=Your_API_Key
```

Response

```
 {
    "predictions": [
        {
            "description": "New Delhi, Delhi, India",
            "matched_substrings": [
                {
                    "length": 9,
                    "offset": 0
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJLbZ-NFv9DDkRzk0gTkm3wlI",
            "reference": "ChIJLbZ-NFv9DDkRzk0gTkm3wlI",
            "structured_formatting": {
                "main_text": "New Delhi",
                "main_text_matched_substrings": [
                    {
                        "length": 9,
                        "offset": 0
                    }
                ],
                "secondary_text": "Delhi, India"
            },
            "terms": [
                {
                    "offset": 0,
                    "value": "New Delhi"
                },
                {
                    "offset": 11,
                    "value": "Delhi"
                },
                {
                    "offset": 18,
                    "value": "India"
                }
            ],
            "types": [
                "locality",
                "political",
                "geocode"
            ]
        },
        {
            "description": "New Delhi, Madhya Pradesh, India",
            "matched_substrings": [
                {
                    "length": 9,
                    "offset": 0
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJF6eOnlmqhTkR2f8IfiLL4bs",
            "reference": "ChIJF6eOnlmqhTkR2f8IfiLL4bs",
            "structured_formatting": {
                "main_text": "New Delhi",
                "main_text_matched_substrings": [
                    {
                        "length": 9,
                        "offset": 0
                    }
                ],
                "secondary_text": "Madhya Pradesh, India"
            },
            "terms": [
                {
                    "offset": 0,
                    "value": "New Delhi"
                },
                {
                    "offset": 11,
                    "value": "Madhya Pradesh"
                },
                {
                    "offset": 27,
                    "value": "India"
                }
            ],
            "types": [
                "locality",
                "political",
                "geocode"
            ]
        },
        {
            "description": "Delhi, NY, USA",
            "matched_substrings": [
                {
                    "length": 5,
                    "offset": 0
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJVS4Od-R43IkRReeLGEBFcv8",
            "reference": "ChIJVS4Od-R43IkRReeLGEBFcv8",
            "structured_formatting": {
                "main_text": "Delhi",
                "main_text_matched_substrings": [
                    {
                        "length": 5,
                        "offset": 0
                    }
                ],
                "secondary_text": "NY, USA"
            },
            "terms": [
                {
                    "offset": 0,
                    "value": "Delhi"
                },
                {
                    "offset": 7,
                    "value": "NY"
                },
                {
                    "offset": 11,
                    "value": "USA"
                }
            ],
            "types": [
                "locality",
                "political",
                "geocode"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with react project and using Autocomplete from @react-google-maps/api the following code should work

```js
<Autocomplete
        onLoad={autocomplete => {
          setAutocomplete(autocomplete)
        }}
        onPlaceChanged={handlePlaceSelect}
        options={{
          types: ['(cities)']
        }}
      >
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter a location"
          name="location"
          id="location"
          onChange={(e) => setSelectedLocationName(e.target.value)}
        />
      </Autocomplete>
```