# Limit on google autocomplete queries?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am planning to use the Google auto complete on my site. Is there a limit on the number of queries I can make?

I am using the exact code listed in this question:
[How to limit google autocomplete results to City and Country only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282026/how-to-limit-google-autocomplete-results-to-city-and-country-only/10170421#10170421)

Answer (score 5):

For Google Places API:

> Applications that submit requests with an API key are allowed 1 000
>   requests per 24 hour period. You can increase the above limit to
>   150 000 requests per 24 hour period by verifying your identity through
>   the Google Developers Console. A credit card is required for
>   verification, by enabling billing in the console.

For Google Places JavaScript Library:

> These limits do not apply to the Places JavaScript Library, which does
>   not require an API key, and is covered by the Google Maps JavaScript
>   API limits.

source: https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/usage

Comment: But the JavaScript API Limits are per Map display, they don't tell anything about the limits on places.

Comment: Following the source link and the documentation for the Places Library versus the API, you still end up using google.maps.places.Autocomplete which uses the API. So either the documentation is wrong, or Google is charging us for something they should not be?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google Maps Javascript API Places library without hesitation. Limits mentioned on other answers applied to Places API, not Places library of the Maps API. From https://developers.google.com/places/uplift

**Choose the right service for your application**

If you are developing a web based application that only needs to search for places, and is not submitting new places or Place Bumps, you should use the Places library of the Maps API rather than using the Places API web service. The Places library assigns a quota to each end user rather than to each key. This means that your available quota increases with your user base rather than being capped at a fixed amount.

Comment: But what is this quota that is assigned to each end user?

Comment: This is new quota introduced since I replied last year.

Answer (score 0):

### Usage Limits

#### The Google Places API has the following query limits:

Users with an **API key** are allowed **1 000 requests per 24 hour period**.

Users who have **verified** their identity through the APIs console are allowed **100 000 requests per 24 hour period**.

A credit card is required for verification, by enabling billing in the console. We ask for your credit card purely to validate your identity. Your card will not be charged for use of the Places API.
While the lower limit is sufficient for development and testing, we recommend enabling the higher limit before launching your application. **It is possible to request additional quota**.

Note that some services may have a multiplier. For example, Text **Search is subject to a 10 times multiplier**, causing each Text Search request to count as 10 requests against your quota.

---

### Update:

I believe that using the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 you are limited with [this policy](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage) and by using the Google Places API you have [these limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#Limits).
I think you should go through verification so you raise the limit from 1000 to 100000

Comment: Francois, Thank you for your response.
I am specifically talking about the auto complete feature. I have implemented it and have been using it for a week now with a valid API key but I don't see any requests recorded in the console reporting.

I found this thread on one of the Google forums
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-places-api/89f4EsHqP44/nc-_nsPYE9IJ

The individual says that there is a limit based on IP for the places API.

Too bad that there is no simple explanation anywhere.

Comment: Thanks. But then why is my console reporting not showing any requests , Any idea?

Comment: was this what you are looking for, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage