# Android address autocomplete using Google maps javascript api v3

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps-api-3

I want to add an address autocomplete to a native android app. I read that there is an option that requires API key and have a limit and another one that doesn't require an API key and have no limit (Google maps javascript api v3?).

Is there an example for the latter? I only found non-native examples and couldn't understand how to convert them into a native one.

Is it even recommended to do it or the API key required method is more recommended?

The example here: https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android shows the api key as part of the app itself but a later note says it should be done on the server and proxied to the app... I'm confused, how should I do it then?

Comment: [Usage limits and billing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage) perhaps? And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671331/limit-on-google-autocomplete-queries) are the limitations on Places API

Comment: The question is whether the java library is relevant when developing a native app or is it just for web app. The other question was about the usage of API key in the code