# Is it possible to restrict map panned, drag and zoom for a specific city?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to restrict map events like pan, drag and zoom for a specific city.

Means If I pass city name like "Boston, MA", Don't allow user to drag or pan out of the city bound.

Is it possible with Google map API?

Answer (score 0):

No Google map is not providing any city limit access. It has a [country restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282026/how-to-limit-google-autocomplete-results-to-city-and-country-only).

Or you have to write a logic to limit access only to a certain distance from the given point. If user drag after that distance then point back to the given Geo-point location.