# Only list the cities name Geocomplete.js or Google Location Autocomplete

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I want to only show the cities name using Geocomplete.js. I have restrict the search to only show the cities. But it is still showing the Country name "United State" at the end, i want to get rid from it.

Any Suggestions please

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Glad that I finally found solution for geocomplete.js! Hope it will be useful to someone.

Solution: Send options with restrictions required to geocomplete function:

```
     var options = {
              types: ['(cities)'],
              componentRestrictions: {}
          };

     $("#source").geocomplete(options);
```

You can also send country-based restrictions. 
with Options like

```
var options = {
          types: ['(cities)'],
          componentRestrictions: {country: ["usa"]}
      };
```

Google Location Autocomplete using google places api solutions was straightforward and [here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282026/how-to-limit-google-autocomplete-results-to-city-and-country-only)

Comment: @FeridMovsumov can you share your code snippet and what you are trying to achieve?