# Geocomplete cities without country information in gecomplete

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocomplete

am using Google Geocomplete to auto suggest my visitors when typing in citie

It works well, but however it suggests country next to the city. For example, if i start to type Chennai, it will suggest Chennai,TamilNadu,India. I need only Chennai, without the country.

Does somebody know how to tell Geocomplete to show only cities without the country?

Thanks

Comment: Use the [Autocomplete Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service) from the Maps API v3 and build your own suggestions list.

Answer (score 0):

The code from here: 
[Only list the cities name Geocomplete.js or Google Location Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781802/only-list-the-cities-name-geocomplete-js-or-google-location-autocomplete)

```
  var options = {
              types: ['(cities)'],
              componentRestrictions: {}
          };

     $("#source").geocomplete(options);
```

Comment: Does that remove the country name from the suggestions, which is what OP asked for?