# How to limit google map api autocomplete jQuery in a country

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I tried to write code to autocomplete addresses with google map api.

First I initialized the map marker and geocoder.

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;

function initialize(){
//MAP
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.016827, -6.835604);
  var options = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);

  //GEOCODER
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });

}
```

Then a jQuery autocomplete I'

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 

  initialize();

  $(function() {
    $("#address").autocomplete({
      //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values
      source: function(request, response) {
        geocoder.geocode( {'address': request.term }, function(results, status) {
          response($.map(results, function(item) {
            return {
              label:  item.formatted_address,
              value: item.formatted_address,
              latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
              longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
            }
          }));
        })
      },
      //This bit is executed upon selection of an address
      select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#latitude").val(ui.item.latitude);
        $("#longitude").val(ui.item.longitude);
        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(ui.item.latitude, ui.item.longitude);
        marker.setPosition(location);
        map.setCenter(location);
      }
    });
  });
```

Now I'd like to limit the autocomplete in one country, I  did some search but I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282026/how-to-limit-google-autocomplete-results-to-city-and-country-only)

But when I tried to do the same in my code I did know.

I hope I'll find some help and thanks

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [Component Filtering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ComponentFiltering) to fully restrict search results

So, according to this, modify your code as follows:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 

  initialize();

  $(function() {
  $("#address").autocomplete({
  //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values
  source: function(request, response) {
    geocoder.geocode( 
    {
      'address': request.term, 
      'componentRestrictions':{'country':'IT'} //any country code...
    }, function(results, status) {
      response($.map(results, function(item) {
        return {
          label:  item.formatted_address,
          value: item.formatted_address,
          latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
          longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
        }
      }));
    })
  },
  //This bit is executed upon selection of an address
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $("#latitude").val(ui.item.latitude);
    $("#longitude").val(ui.item.longitude);
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(ui.item.latitude, ui.item.longitude);
    marker.setPosition(location);
    map.setCenter(location);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found How to limit the research It just I should concatenate the adresse with city and the country

```
geocoderar.geocode( {'address': request.term + ' Rabat, MA' }
```

in my case Rabat is the city and MA is the country there is a code for each country this is the [link for country code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2)