# how to limit autocomplete results (without map) to a city

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the code which gives autocompletion with Lat/long. 
I want the results to be specific to a city. 
I mean, the search for autocompletion should be restricted to a city.
Help me.. as soon as possible

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#autocomplete").on('focus', function () {
    geolocate();
});

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */ (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
        types: ['geocode']
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        fillInAddress();
    });
}

function fillInAddress() {

    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    document.getElementById("latitude").value = place.geometry.location.lat();
    document.getElementById("longitude").value = place.geometry.location.lng();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
        document.getElementById(component).value = '';
        document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
        }
    }
}

function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
            position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            document.getElementById("latitude").value = latitude;
            document.getElementById("longitude").value = longitude;

            autocomplete.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(geolocation, geolocation));
        });
    }

}

initialize();

</script>
      </head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="locationField">
    <input id="autocomplete" size="60" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text"></input>
</div>
<table id="address">
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Lat</td>
        <td class="slimField">
            <input type="text" class="field" id="latitude"></input>
        </td>
        <td class="label">Long</td>
        <td class="wideField">
            <input type="text" class="field" id="longitude"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What you mean `restricted to a city`?

Comment: In the autocompletion address field I want the search done for a particular city only lets say Bangalore,India. If I am typing "Korm...." it shouuld suggest me "Kormangala" in bangalore only

Comment: you need to check it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282026/how-to-limit-google-autocomplete-results-to-city-and-country-only

Comment: Thanks but that only restricts to a country not city also "with maps" , I want for "without maps"

Comment: you can hide the map with the css

Comment: Can you edit my code by code given in stackoverflow.com/questions/8282026/… link

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zK5FN/2/ that will tell you the city based on lat and long. 
It uses ipinfo.io

Comment: thanks for your answer but what I need is let me explain with you an example-
In the autocompletion address field I want the search done for a particular city only lets say Bangalore,India. If I am typing "Korm...." it shouuld suggest me "Kormangala" in bangalore only