# AngularJS - Restrict Country in Google AutoComplete

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I use plugin "ion-google-places" in my ionic/angularjs App and I want restrict suggest (I want only French places, cities, routes in suggest).
The problem is when I tap an address, a lot of countries are suggest (Germany, USA, etc.)

I've try this below but it doesn't work ...

This is my HTML :

```
<ion-google-place placeholder="Lieu" ng-model="event.addressid" geocode-options="geocodeOptions" />
```

This is my ControllerJS :

```
$scope.geocodeOptions = {
  componentRestrictions: {
    country : 'FR'
  }
};
```

The "ion-google-places" repo : https://github.com/israelidanny/ion-google-place

Thank's all in advance !

Comment: I came across the same problem and found this other thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282026/how-to-limit-google-autocomplete-results-to-city-and-country-only

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var placeName = "new york";

var options = {
  componentRestrictions: {country: "us"} //  <== Country code name
};

 var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(placeName, options);
```