# Removing state name from auto suggestion list so that user selects particular area/city

Tags: google-places-api

I am using the google places api to create a textbox that is input field for user to select his/her preferred location. I want that user specifies the exact area name where he lives.

The problem is google places api gives me:
1.Mumbai (State Name)
2.Mumbai Vashi (City in Mumbai)
3.Mumbai Thane (City in Mumbai)

I want to remove the first option OR all the state name like Mumbai, Hyderabad, Karnataka so that user only has choice to select his area/city.

I am fairly new to UI and google places api. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

function initAutocomplete() {

```
    var options = {
        componentRestrictions: { country: "IN" }
    };
    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.

    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

}

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD9CiSrNomU7HPw5PLIpFZYP6NXXOq0dlE&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
```

I am using google places api javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Google Places API Web Service, the Google Places API Javascript Library, the Google Places API for Android, or the Google Places API for iOS?

Assuming you're using the Web Service, then you want to use the `types=(cities)` parameter in your Place Autocomplete requests.  For example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Mumbai&types=(cities)&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

The `(cities)` type, and other types like `(regions)`, are documented in [Google Developers guide for Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_types).