# limit google map search places autocomplete within a boundary of a city?

Tags: google-maps

how to limit the google place search boundary within a city, and establishments.

I want the user to be able to search establishments within a certain area - city

```
var options = {
                componentRestrictions: {
                    country: 'PH'}
            };
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
            autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Autocomplete`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) creates a text input field on your web page, supplies predictions of places in a UI pick list, and returns place details in response to a getPlace() request.

The (`cities`) type collection instructs the Places service to return results that match either `locality` or `administrative_area3`.

Use the `componentRestrictions` option to restrict the autocomplete search to a particular country. The following code restricts the results to cities within France.

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
types: ['(cities)'],
componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

For more details on how to limit searches, check this tutorial page: [How to limit google autocomplete results to City and Country only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282026/how-to-limit-google-autocomplete-results-to-city-and-country-only)