# Google Autocomplete Cities FIlter to Uk in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[Image of errors occuring in my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkcHD.png)
I want to restrict google autocomplete suggestions about cities only to Uk.
But whenever I try to filter it only to uk . I get no suggestion even not from whole world or uk. It is a wordpress site search built into theme.
I got that code in my theme directory. If anybody can help me to make proper changes to that code to get the right result that would be greatly appreciated.

```
function autofilllocation()
{

    $(".location-autocomplete").each(function(){

        var element = $(this).get(0);

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(

            element ,

            { types: ['geocode'] }

        );



        if($(element).hasClass('filter-location')) {

            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {

                $( document.body ).trigger( 'ajax_filter_search' );

            });

        }

    });

}
```

Help me PLZ
THere is a pic of errors occuring.

Comment: Plz anybody help me??

Comment: Where in your code you try to filter only to `UK` cities?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit google autocomplete results to City and Country only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282026/how-to-limit-google-autocomplete-results-to-city-and-country-only)

Comment: That is the code that is giving me all cites in world.

Comment: What code? And did you check the duplicate that I posted?

Comment: No that code is not working. Above posted code works but give all cities but your code give no suggestions.

Comment: even when i repace geocode with cities it also dont work

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xkcHD.png

Image of errors occuring on website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply a component restriction by country. Please have a look at autocomplete options object in documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#AutocompleteOptions

In your code you can do it like:

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        element ,
        { 
            types: ['geocode'],
            componentRestrictions: {
                country: 'GB'
            }
        }
);
```

Example on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/bomawo/edit?html,output

Comment: First time works after editing code but next time after reloading page don't work. But after clicking search, on next page again clicking on search field it shows the suggestions.

Comment: I think the error message is self explanatory. You load JavaScript API more than 1 time. Analyze your code and ensure that you load the API only once.

Comment: Worked Another Plugin was also loading api. Disabled it and worked like a charm.