# How do I specific the map only available for specific country?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-platform

I used google cloud MAP API to autocomplete the address field. But I want to limit it just to specific country. For example, the list address is for Malaysia address only. Here I attached the coding to get the address autocomplete using google MAP API. Currently, it shows and list the address that outside Malaysia too. I just want it to be in Malaysia. How do I do that?

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/home/azmi/Desktop/maphuhu/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<style>
.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
</style>
<script>
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
      var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
      };

      function initAutocomplete() {
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
        // location types.
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
            {types: ['geocode']});

        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
        // fields in the form.
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
      }

      function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
          document.getElementById(component).value = '';
          document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }

        // Get each component of the address from the place details
        // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
          var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
          if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
          }
        }
      }

      // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
      // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
      function geolocate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geolocation = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
              center: geolocation,
              radius: position.coords.accuracy
            });
            autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
          });
        }
      }
</script>
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Address</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
   <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
      onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" class="form-control">
      <br>
   <div id="address">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Street address</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="street_number" disabled="true">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Route</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="route" disabled="true">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">City</label>
            <input class="form-control field" id="locality" disabled="true">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6"> 
            <label class="control-label">State</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Zip code</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="postal_code" disabled="true">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Country</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="country" disabled="true">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>  
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key23&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>  
<script src="/home/azmi/Desktop/maphuhu/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" async defer></script>  
<script src="/home/azmi/Desktop/maphuhu/bootstrap.min.js" async defer></script>  

</body>
</html>
```

This is the example output:

[image: Output]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282026/how-to-limit-google-autocomplete-results-to-city-and-country-only

Comment: Duplicate of [How to limit google autocomplete results to City and Country only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282026/how-to-limit-google-autocomplete-results-to-city-and-country-only)

Answer (score 0):

Add [`componentRestrictions`](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#ComponentRestrictions) to the [`AutocompleteOptions`](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#AutocompleteOptions).

The [ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) for Malaysia is 'my'.

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'my'},
    types: ['geocode']
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/xkvw8db0/1/)

[image: screenshot of result]

**code snippet:**

```js
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      componentRestrictions: {
        country: 'my'
      },
      types: ['geocode']
    });

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Address</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" class="form-control">
      <br>
      <div id="address">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Street address</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="street_number" disabled="true">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Route</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="route" disabled="true">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">City</label>
            <input class="form-control field" id="locality" disabled="true">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">State</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Zip code</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="postal_code" disabled="true">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Country</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="country" disabled="true">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" async defer></script>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```