# Google place autocomplete address from one country only

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

I am using Google Autocomplete Place API it is working fine by using the below piece of code.

```
autocompleteform = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
             (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
                {}
            );
```

Now the issue is it is auto-suggesting addresses from the whole world.
I want to show the result of a particular country let say Switzerland, how to do this?

Comment: Your question is not about Google Cloud Platform. You should change the tag to "google-places", "google-places-api" or similar.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to limit google autocomplete results to City and Country only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282026/how-to-limit-google-autocomplete-results-to-city-and-country-only)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself using API documentation and example.
Here is the line of code that I added.

```
/* Restrict to switzerland only */
 autocompleteform.setComponentRestrictions(
     {
         'country': ['CH']
      }
 );
```